# How can I programmatically get the ABI compatibility level (minor version) of my Ruby installation?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out a way to determine the [ABI compatibility level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60842308/3486353) (i.e. the minor version) of the Ruby installation on any given machine.

I know that I can determine the full version number by running `"RUBY_VERSION"` in `irb` - for example, on my machine, it would currently return "2.6.5". But I'm looking for a solution that will tell me just the minor version - so for both 2.6.5 or 2.6.6, I'd simply want "2.6.0" as the output.

Is there a straightforward way to get this info, short of simply trimming the full version and appending a `.0`?

Comment: You could look at where your gems are installed, as that has a path component that explains, but since the 1.8 days that zero rule has held true.

Comment: Note that this rule goes out the window if you're using a non-MRI Ruby like JRuby.

Comment: Yeah, as it happens I'm actually trying to use this to predict where my gems will install to, in a peculiar situation on a newly created ephemeral CI machine. If there's any way to have Ruby or Bundler print out the directory where gems would be installed when none are yet present, I'd take that too - it's entirely possible this is an X/Y problem.

Comment: Check `gem env`. On my system the first `GEM PATHS` entry has that version at the very end of the path, `.../.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0` RVM and such will treat this differently but the same principle applies. Not sure if there's a Rubygems API method for that or not.

Comment: Interesting! Yeah, looks like there's a few things in there I could potentially parse it out from. Thanks! That just might work if there's no better answer.

Comment: If you've got a solution of any kind it's worth adding as a self-answer as I don't think this is settled anywhere.

Comment: Came across the fact that `gem env gemdir` gives a much more specific output that contains a path similar to what you cited, and is usable in my case. If nobody comes through with a better solution in some time, I'll try to write a quick self-answer based on that approach which works for a more general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way I know of to get the ABI compatibility level programmatically.

However, given your comments, it seems that you are *not* actually caring about the ABI compatibility level but about the RubyGems Gem installation path. Since this path can be configured by the user in a configuration file, environment variable or command line argument, I think it would make much more sense to ask RubyGems for the Gem installation path using the [`Gem::dir`](http://docs.seattlerb.org/rubygems/Gem.html#method-c-dir) method instead of asking Ruby for the ABI compatibility level:

```ruby
Gem.dir
#=> "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0"
```